# Why can't BIRTReportGenerator find my source file?

Tags: android, fortify, sourceanalyser

I'm trying to build a fortify report using BIRTReportGenerator as outlined in the SCA user guide. The scans work fine and generate an fpr file, but when I run the report generator I get the following error.

```
FPR source file not found or not readable.
```

Here are the commands I'm using. These were cut and pasted straight from the user guide. The only thing modified is the paths.

```
sourceanalyzer -b myproject -clean
sourceanalyzer -b myproject -cp /Users/ginger.mcmurray/Mobuyle-Android-New-Ui/MobuyleCore/libs -Dcom.fortify.sca.SuppressLowSeverity=true -Dcom.fortify.sca.LowSeverityCutoff=10.0 -jdk 1.6 MobuyleCore/src
sourceanalyzer -b myproject -scan -f results.fpr
BIRTReportGenerator -template "OWASP Top 10" -source results.fpr -format PDF -showSuppressed --Version "OWASP Top 10 2013" --UseFortifyPriorityOrder -output MyOWASP_Top10_Report.pdf
```

If I use ReportGenerator instead, everything works. However, I need the ability to create BIRT reports for our security department.

This is for an android java project, just in case that changes anything.

Also, I get a lot of unknown function and reference issues for things that are inside my jar files, despite including the path in the command.

Output from BIRTReportGenerator with -debug option.

```
Start VM: -Xms40m
-Xmx1088m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Awb.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dcom.fortify.InstallRoot=../../../../../../..
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.fortify.InstallRoot=/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/bin/..
-Xmx1000M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/Auditworkbench.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os macosx
-ws cocoa
-arch x86_64
-launcher /Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/Auditworkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
-name HPE Security Fortify Report Generation
--launcher.library /Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/Auditworkbench.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
-startup /Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/Auditworkbench.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-application com.hp.fortify.birt.report.generator.console.Application
-data /Users/ginger.mcmurray/.fortify/BIRT16.10/workspace
-configuration /Users/ginger.mcmurray/.fortify/BIRT16.10/configuration442
-template OWASP Top 10
-source results.fpr
-format PDF
-showSuppressed
--Version OWASP Top 10 2013
--UseFortifyPriorityOrder
-debug
-output MyOWASP_Top10_Report.pdf
-consoleLog
-vm /Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1088m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Awb.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dcom.fortify.InstallRoot=../../../../../../..
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.fortify.InstallRoot=/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/bin/..
-Xmx1000M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/Auditworkbench.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar 
Configuration location:
    file:/Users/ginger.mcmurray/.fortify/BIRT16.10/configuration442/
Configuration file:
    file:/Users/ginger.mcmurray/.fortify/BIRT16.10/configuration442/config.ini loaded
Install location:
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Loading timestamp file from:
     file:/Users/ginger.mcmurray/.fortify/BIRT16.10/configuration442/   .baseConfigIniTimestamp
    No timestamp file found
Timestamps found: 
     config.ini in the base: 1458848541000
     remembered -1
Shared configuration location:
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/plugins/
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar
Debug options:
    file:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.10/Core/private-bin/awb/eclipse/Auditworkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 5
Starting application: 864
FPR source file not found or not readable.
```

Comment: Try running the `BIRTReportGenerator` command with the `-debug` option.  Any useful information?

Comment: You mentioned 'my jar files' are in the path, is this the `-cp` path specified?  Is it in that specific directory or subdirectory?  try adding `**\*.jar` to the end of the `-cp` option.

Comment: @SBurris, I added the output when -debug is used. Also, the jars are all in the specified folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the `BIRTReportGenerator` in versions 16.10/16.20 when on the MacOS having to do with relative paths.

This has been fixed in 17.10 (current version as of Oct 2017).

I do not know of a workaround, you can try contacting Fortify Technical Support (fortifytechsupport@hpe.com) and see if they have a workaround.

Comment: I updated the call to BIRTReportGenerator -template "OWASP Top 10" -source /Users/ginger.mcmurray/Mobuyle-Android-New-Ui/results.fpr -format PDF -showSuppressed --UseFortifyPriorityOrder -debug -output /Users/ginger.mcmurray/Mobuyle-Android-New-Ui/MyOWASP_Top10_Report.pdf but still get the same error. Is there somewhere else I need to change the paths?

Comment: Updated, looked closer a bug, I misspoke when I said absolute values.  Sorry

Comment: No luck. I upgraded to 17.10 and still get the same error.